# How to get pip to install packages into the virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-venv

On Windows 8, i have the following structure for a Python 3 project:

```
../Project/
../Project/app/app.py
../Project/app/setup.py
```

From the app folder, i invoke the following commands to create and enter into a virtual environment:

```
pyvenv.py venv
cd venv\Scripts
activate.bat
cd ../..
```

Now i would like to install the `Nose` unit testing framework into my virtual environment:

```
pip install nose
```

... and Nose gets installed into the global folder (In my case, C:\Python33).

When i invoke `python setup.py install`, my custom module gets installed to the virtual environment. Why doesn't PIP do the same?

Comment: did you install pip in you virtual envirnoment? probably original pip, found in windows path is invoked

Comment: @alko No, i totally missed that. However, when i try to run the "ez_setup.py" from the virtual environment, to get ready for PIP installation, it is installed to the global Python folder, not the virtual environment.

Comment: i'm not sure if ez_setup is compatible with venv

Comment: @alko Sorry, new to Python. Did you install Setuptools and PIP from manually downloaded source files in the venv? There is no distribute_setup.py in my venv folder.

Comment: This problem is **no longer reproducible**. Modern versions of `venv` will bootstrap Pip automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works well for me after following [docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/venv.html#venv-def):

> Common installation tools such as `Distribute` and `pip` work as expected
>   with venvs - i.e. when a venv is active, they install Python packages
>   into the venv without needing to be told to do so explicitly. **Of
>   course, you need to install them into the venv first**: this could be
>   done by running `distribute_setup.py` with the venv activated, followed
>   by running `easy_install pip`. Alternatively, you could download the
>   source tarballs and run `python setup.py install` after unpacking, with
>   the venv activated.